# What class airspace is depicted in the magenta colored area southeast of the Lake Havasu City, Arizona AIrport?

Tags: airspace, non-towered-airport

What class airspace is depicted in the picture below within the wide magenta colored bar southeast of the Lake Havasu City, Arizona Airport (on the [Phoenix, Arizona Sectional Chart](https://skyvector.com/?ll=34.540375040898674,-114.37374932246301&chart=25&zoom=1&fpl=undefined))?  What are the vertical boundaries of this airspace?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

By the **[legend](https://skyvector.com/?ll=35.22110160678794,-117.00475862935181&chart=25&zoom=1&fpl=undefined)**, that should be *"Class E Airspace with floor 700 ft. above surface that laterally abuts 1200ft or higher Class E Airspace"*

Answer (score 4):

The airspace for KHII is defined per [74 FR 43029](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2009/08/26/E9-20278/modification-of-class-e-airspace-lake-havasu-az) as [class E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airspace_class_(United_States)#Class_E) Sectionals such as skyvector show the area as shaded magenta. which means that this particular flavor of class E begins at 700' and extends to the class A.

> That airspace extending upward from 700 feet above the surface within a 6.7-mile radius of Lake Havasu City Airport and within 1 mile each side of the Lake Havasu City Airport 150° bearing extending from the 6.7-mile radius to 13 miles southeast of the Lake Havasu City Airport, excluding that airspace with a 2.3-mile radius of Chemehuevi Valley Airport. That airspace extending upward from 1,200 feet above the surface bounded by a line beginning at lat. 34°42′47″ N., long. 114°29′37″ W.; to lat. 34°42′47″ N., long. 114°12′06″ W.; to lat. 34°23′00″ N., long. 114°12′06″ W.; to lat. 34°17′19″ N., long. 114°32′12″ W.; thence to the point of beginning.

Note particularly

> and within 1 mile each side of the Lake Havasu City Airport 150° bearing extending from the 6.7-mile radius to 13 miles southeast of the Lake Havasu City Airport

The rule says that the airspace was created for execution of RNAV approaches. Not sure why the 13 mile rectangle is required for RNAV approaches though.

Comment: @JWalters, that has been addressed.

Comment: @photoscientist - On the RNAV approach there is a tower, about 800 AGL tall approximate 8 miles from the end of rwy 32.  It's possible the approach designer considered this when constructing the extension.  This would ensure (theoretically) that a VFR aircraft passing above the tower in order to remain clear would be required to have 3 miles vis and meet cloud clearance requirements of controlled airspace (class E extension).  This would help protect the aircraft on the RNAV approach. Designers have some discretion in their decision making when building the approach and advising on extensions.